# MongoDB Atlas Cluster connections are always capped

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am using express server, mongoose and MongoDB Atlas for the backend. My application is hosted on heroku.
I open the connection just once on server bootstrap:

```js
db()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to the database')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

`db()` looks like this:

```js
function db() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, poolSize: 25});

    mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
      console.log('open')
      resolve("Connection has been made.");
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
      reject("Connection error: " + error.message);
    })
  })
}
```

Then, within just 2 hours I reach 500 opened connections which result in errors from Atlas.
Restarting dynos helps, but I can't do it every 2 hours.
What can it be and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are opening connections and not closing them, eventually you hit the connection limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read that it is a good practice not to close the connection. Anyway, what is the proper place in the code to close it?

Comment: One would normally have one outstanding connection per process. You are apparently making more.

Comment: Hm, once my server bootstraps the connection function executes and that's it. I have no clue why it would execute again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael Kutateladze Since you are not closing the connection after the use, the number of concurrent requests to your app is creating more connections and resulting in exceeding the MongoDB Atlas connections limit. So, it is important that you either close the connection in your logic after the use or go for creating a connection pool that will improvise the use case.

Again, exceeding the connection limit for the Atlas cluster may occur for different reasons and Atlas tiers have different connection limits based on cluster size. So, larger cluster tiers will have a higher connection limit. So, all these things worth considering if it affects your application and the connection limit on production.

Example of Connection pool logic:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;  //reusable db instance

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Make sure you start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers like below
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  db.collection("replicaset_mongo_client_collection").find({}, function(err, docs) {
    //code here
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! "Make sure you start the application after the database connection is ready" solved the issue